# Counting hours in format H:mm in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column on hours looking like that:

```
|time|
--------------
8:54
5:32
4:34
7:12
12:55
10:32
3:54
2:35
```

I want to count how many rows I have with more than 5 hours? something with the format of the hours makes it problematic for me.. the format is varchar (text).

how can I do it? any thought?

Thanks!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was a bit tricky but it worked:

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT cast(substring(hours, 1, len(hours) -3) as INT) as TIME
    FROM your_table
              )

  SELECT count(*) as MORE_THAN_5_HOURS
  FROM A
  WHERE TIME >= 5
```

you remove the last 3 letters of the text you have as hours (8:54 will become 8)
then you convert it to INT putting all of what you did in a table called A.
and then you count all rows in A with TIME above 5.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

```
Select Cnt = count(*)
 From  YourTable
 Where try_convert(decimal(10,2),replace([time],':','.')) > 5
```

**Results**

```
Cnt
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

- 1st step: convert data into `TIME(0)` data type.
- 2nd step: get hour part of it via `DATEPART(hour, ...)` built-in
  function.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, hour_min VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl (hour_min) VALUES
('8:54'),
('5:32'),
('4:34'),
('7:12'),
('12:55'),
('10:32'),
('3:54'),
('2:35');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- just to see
SELECT * 
    , _hour = DATEPART(hour, TRY_CAST(hour_min + ':00' AS TIME(0)))
FROM @tbl;

-- real deal
SELECT [counter] = COUNT(*)
FROM @tbl
WHERE DATEPART(hour, TRY_CAST(hour_min + ':00' AS TIME(0))) >= 5;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+
| counter |
+---------+
|       5 |
+---------+
```